# On this aim / to this aim / with this aim

Tags: word-choice

Can we start a sentence: on this aim/with this aim, when we want to use it as a synonym of "For this purpose" ?

Comment: I would prefer "for the aim of" or "for the purpose of" or "for the goal of"; the problem I see is beginning a sentence with a raw pronoun (no antecedent). Perhaps if there was more context there would be a more complete answer.

Comment: thank you, but the next answer fits better to the context.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would say no, you cannot start the sentence with "On this aim" or "For this aim".

But yes, you can start the sentence using "With this aim", as long as you provide the purpose in the prior sentences.

For example, if you have already described the purpose, you could then say "With this aim, we structured the experiment to measure these four criteria: [...]."